# AM_PATH_PYTHON for python2 and python3

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, m4

I am using automake's macro `AM_PATH_PYTHON` to find the `pythondir` variable.

Till now I have been calling it without arguments which defaults to python 2.7 on Ubuntu. Now I also want to build it for `python3.x` (3.3 specifically).

Is there a way where I can call `AM_PATH_PYTHON([3])` to get `python3.3`, store all the generated variables using `AC_SUBST` in a `python3` specific variable and then call `AM_PATH_PYTHON([2])` for `python2`.

I am doing this

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON([3])
AC_SUBST(PYTHON3,$PYTHON)
AC_SUBST(HAVE_PYTHON3,$HAVE_PYTHON)
AC_SUBST(PYTHON3_VERSION,$PYTHON_VERSION)
AC_SUBST(PYTHON3_PREFIX,$PYTHON_PREFIX)
AC_SUBST(PYTHON3_EXEC_PREFIX,$PYTHON_EXEC_PREFIX)
AC_SUBST(PYTHON3_PLATFORM,$PYTHON_PLATFORM)
AC_SUBST(python3dir,$pythondir)
AC_SUBST(pkgpython3dir,$pkgpythondir)
AC_SUBST(py3execdir,$pyexecdir)
AC_SUBST(pkgpy3execdir,$pkgpyexecdir)

unset PYTHON
unset HAVE_PYTHON
unset PYTHON_VERSION
unset PYTHON_PREFIX
unset PYTHON_EXEC_PREFIX
unset PYTHON_PLATFORM
unset pythondir
unset pkgpythondir
unset pyexecdir
unset pkgpyexecdir
AM_PATH_PYTHON([2])
```

Even after doing all these the second `AM_PATH_PYTHON` is not rewriting the variables. I know these are macros, but there should be a way to do this. The Makefile shows

```
py3execdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.3/site-packages
pyexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.3/site-packages
python3dir = ${prefix}/lib/python3.3/site-packages
pythondir = ${prefix}/lib/python3.3/site-packages
```

Answer (score 3):

If you end up going the rewrite-the-macro route, you might want to make use of the variable [_AM_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_LIST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173018/1207160) to write wrapper macros `AM_PATH_PYTHON2` and `AM_PATH_PYTHON3` that just set `_AM_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_LIST` and call `AM_PATH_PYTHON` with an extra suffix argument.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this has been fixed in a recent release of automake.
If, like me, you are on an older version that is not fixed, you can plug in

```
unset am_cv_pathless_PYTHON
unset PYTHON
```

between runs to make it work.