# How do I run a Python 3 script on a user's system when they may also have Python 2.7 installed?

Tags: python, makefile

I'm trying to run python 3 scripts as part of a Makefile target that can be used on Linux or Windows (msys). What is the correct way it invoke Python 3 when the system may also have Python 2.7 installed?

It seems that:

- `python script.py` doesn't work, because on systems that have Python 2.7 installed, that points at the 2.7 version.
- `python3 script.py` doesn't work, because if you only have Python 3 installed it names the executable `python.exe` on Windows.
- `py -3 script.py` doesn't work on Linux because the `py` shunt only exists on Windows.

Is there a good example out there of how to do this correctly?

Comment: Don't know much about Windows, but Makefiles are quite often generated from a template by some autoconfig type tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a general solution which will work out of the box without user cooperation. The usual way to do this is to specify a reasonable default in your `Makefile` and allow the user to override it.  Perhaps something like

```
PY3 = python3

py_ver := $(shell $(PY3) -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info.major)')
ifneq ($(py_ver),3)
  $(error Need PY3 to point to a working Python 3 executable)
endif

# now use $(PY3) wherever you previously used python
```

Now you'd use `make PY3=/usr/local/bin/python` or whatever to run this with a different path for the binary.

If you use Automake there are built-in macros for Python 2 and Python 3; see also [AM_PATH_PYTHON for python2 and python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541207/am-path-python-for-python2-and-python3)

Answer (score 0):

What about just implementing what you found:

```
which python3 python | head -1
```

Or said differently, try python3, if that fails fallback to python.